# how to split a multiple character string into table in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server

i have a string like this :

> "a:13:{s:7:"answers";a:4:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:35:"a. CH4+ 2O2 ? CO2
>   + 2H2O";s:7:"correct";s:3:"yes";s:7:"default";s:2:"no";}i:1;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:37:"b.
>   2CH4+ 2O2 ? 2CO2  +
>   2H2O";s:7:"correct";s:2:"no";s:7:"default";s:2:"no";}i:2;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:37:"c.
>   3CH4+ 2O2 ? 2CO2  +
>   3H2O";s:7:"correct";s:2:"no";s:7:"default";s:2:"no";}i:3;a:3:{s:4:"text";s:37:"d.
>   2CH4+ 2O2 ? 2CO2  +
>   4H2O";s:7:"correct";s:2:"no";s:7:"default";s:2:"no";}"

i want to split this string and extract specific values from this and then save that values into my db table. i have found a functon for this

---FUNCTION---

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[stringfind] (@String nvarchar(4000) )      
Returns @Stringtable Table (ID nvarchar(200))  As      

Begin     
 -- Append comma    
 --Set @String =  @String + '"'     
 -- Indexes to keep the position of searching    
 Declare @Pos1 Int    
 Declare @Pos2 Int    

 -- Start from first character     
 Set @Pos1=1    
 Set @Pos2=1    

 While @Pos1<Len(@String)    
 Begin    
  Set @Pos1 = CharIndex('"',@String,@Pos2)
  Set @Pos2 = CharIndex('"',@String,@Pos1+1)     
  Insert @Stringtable Select  Cast(Substring(@String,@Pos1+1,@Pos2-@Pos1-1) As nvarchar(200))  
  -- Go to next non comma character    
  Set @Pos2=@Pos2+1  
  -- Search from the next charcater    
  Set @Pos1 = @Pos2+1    
 End     
 Return    
End
```

but this function only creates a temporary table but i want values to be stored in a permenant tsble of database.. can anyone help me through this plz?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use a stored procedure instead.

Comment: i cant find a sp for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsert
(
    @String nvarchar(4000)
)
AS
INSERT INTO YourTable(YourColumn)
SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[stringfind](@String)
```